# Updating field based on specified number of records less than total (e.g., 1000 out of 5000 records)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Background:** I'm using Access 2010 to manage and track tax bills being researched and paid. They are received in Excel format and imported into the database, then I have a bunch of queries that I run to identify research items. At any given time, there are thousands of bills in various stages, but the largest portion are always those that are simply ready to pay. I've automated it so that records labeled with a "batch number" (identifier for a group of bills in my company's software system) selected from a dropdown get exported in the correct format for our software for payment. Because of county tax office restrictions, I can only pay 1500 bills at a time.

**Question/Issue:** I need a [better] way to update the "batch number" on 1500 records (or less) at a time, out of a recordset that's much larger. Basically, I want the ability to type in a number and create a group (based on updating the "batch number") with that many bills in it.

**Example:** If the total number of bills ready to pay was 3900, then I would make the following:

- BATCH-001 - 1500 bills
- BATCH-002 - 1500 bills
- BATCH-003 - 900 bills

**What I've Tried:** I googled like crazy and managed to patch together something that *does* work, but with a large number of records it locks up my computer...not surprising, given what it's doing, but I had to give it a shot! It's iterating through all of the records and flagging a boolean field to True until the count is reached. Then I use that boolean field to filter an update query. See below.

```
    Private Sub cmdCreateBatch_Click()

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        Dim intRecordNum As Integer
        Dim intBatchSize As Integer

        Me.Recordset.MoveFirst

        intBatchSize = Me.txtBatchSize
        intRecordNum = Me.CurrentRecord

        If intRecordNum < intBatchSize Then

            Do Until intRecordNum > intBatchSize
                Me.chkInclude = True
                Me.Recordset.MoveNext
                intRecordNum = Me.CurrentRecord
            Loop
        End If

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdateBatchNumber", acViewNormal, acEdit
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdateCheckBoxtoFalse", acViewNormal, acEdit

        Me.Requery

        MsgBox "Bill batch has been created."

        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    End Sub
```

I'm still a VBA newbie, but eagerly learning everything I can! I appreciate any and all assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think probably the approach to take would be to run a single query to work out which 1500 records need adding to a batch, rather than stepping through your records and updating them individually until you've done 1500. Assuming your `bills` table has a numeric Primary Key then you could use something like

```
select max(BillID) As BatchEnd from 
    (select top 1500 BillID from Bills
     where BatchNumber Is Null and Status = {ready to batch}
     order by BillID) As X
```

Note that you don't have to worry about explicitly specifying a small batch at the end; if there aren't 1500 records left unbatched then the `top 1500` will just give you all the remaining unbatched records. Having found this maximum unbatched BillID, you then don't even need to set a flag (`chkInclude`), you can just go straight for an update

```
update Bills 
set BatchNumber = {whatever your next BatchNumber is},
    Status = {new status}
where BatchNumber Is Null and BillID <= {variable where you stored BatchEnd}
```

Comment: Who dat, [**S K I P P Y**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_(peanut_butter)), [**S K I P P Y**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_(peanut_butter)), ya!!

Comment: I was hoping for a way to specify a number in case I want to do less than 1500 for some reason; however, I think this will work well enough, and I can always manually create a batch in those random cases. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I think you should be able to use your input variable in the `(select top {intBatchSize} BillID...` part of the statement.